# Connecting excel to skype. reference error

Tags: excel, vba, reference, skype

so im trying to pair skype and excel. But i can't seem to make it run. I thought i selected the correct references and even directly selected SkypeComLib.dll but to no avail. I've included a photo of the references i have selected as well as the error. the code i'm trying to run is a sample i found online. The debug highlights "Set aSkype = New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype" [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpXqa.jpg)

[references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDNnC.jpg)

```
Sub Test()

Dim aSkype As SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
Set aSkype = New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
Dim oChat As Chat
Dim skUser As SKYPE4COMLib.User
Set skUser = aSkype.User("user_name")
Set oChat = aSkype.CreateChatWith(skUser.Handle)
oChat.OpenWindow
oChat.SendMessage "automated message"

End Sub
```

Comment: also if you know how to get the skype toolbar on excel that would help a bunch.

Comment: Did you register the DLL?

Comment: yes but im not sure of the proper file path. I've done c:\program files (x86)\skype\ skype4com.dll and i've also did c:\program files\common files\ \skype\ skype4com.dll. When i tried to find it in excel com add-in it said something along the lines of "not excel add in". .